# SQLite Performance for querying large amounts of tick data

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have a database with a decently large amount of tick data of all 229 stocks in the S&P/TSX Composite Index. For reference, a single day's worth of data is about 13 million rows.

here's a snippet of data:

```
ID  TICKER  TIME                     TYPE      VALUE  SIZE  EXCHANGE  CONDN_CODES  BUY_BRK  SELL_BRK
--  ------  -----------------------  --------  -----  ----  --------  -----------  -------  --------
15  ABX CN  2021-05-07T13:30:00.000  BEST_BID  29.21  918   T
16  ABX CN  2021-05-07T13:30:00.000  BEST_BID  29.21  917   T
17  ABX CN  2021-05-07T13:30:00.000  BEST_BID  29.21  927   T
18  ABX CN  2021-05-07T13:30:00.000  BEST_BID  29.21  928   T
19  ABX CN  2021-05-07T13:30:00.000  TRADE     29.21  100   T         OPA,XT       85       85
20  ABX CN  2021-05-07T13:30:00.000  TRADE     29.21  100   T         OPA,XT       79       79
21  ABX CN  2021-05-07T13:30:00.000  TRADE     29.21  200   T         OPA,XT       79       79
22  ABX CN  2021-05-07T13:30:00.000  TRADE     29.21  100   T         OPA,XT       79       79
```

One of the things that's interesting is analyzing whether a trade occurred on the bid side, or on the offer side. So I wrote a query that will append the latest best bid, and the latest best ask, to each trade. When running the query, the output looks like this:

```
ID      TICKER  TIME                     TYPE   VALUE  SIZE  EXCHANGE  CONDN_CODES  BUY_BRK  SELL_BRK  LATEST_BBID  LATEST_BASK
------  ------  -----------------------  -----  -----  ----  --------  -----------  -------  --------  -----------  -----------
267795  AC CN   2021-05-07T13:45:03.000  TRADE  24.5   100   T                      2        1         24.5         24.51
267797  AC CN   2021-05-07T13:45:03.000  TRADE  24.5   100   C                      1        79        24.5         24.51
267803  AC CN   2021-05-07T13:45:03.000  TRADE  24.5   1     B         MN           80       79        24.49        24.5
267817  AC CN   2021-05-07T13:45:05.000  TRADE  24.5   200   T                      79       80        24.49        24.5
267834  AC CN   2021-05-07T13:45:07.000  TRADE  24.52  50    B         MN           80       212       24.5         24.52
267837  AC CN   2021-05-07T13:45:07.000  TRADE  24.5   100   T                      2        79        24.5         24.51
267858  AC CN   2021-05-07T13:45:08.000  TRADE  24.48  100   X                      79       9         24.48        24.5
267859  AC CN   2021-05-07T13:45:08.000  TRADE  24.48  100   O                      1        9         24.48        24.5
```

So here's the problem:

The query is pretty slow. I run it on a per-stock basis, and each query takes a couple of seconds. Iterating over 229 different stocks, doing some calculations, and then outputting some summary stats take around 5 minutes, which is too slow for my liking.

the query is written as follows (ticker and dates are hardcoded for ease of reading):

```
SELECT 
    ID, TICKER, TIME, TYPE, VALUE, SIZE, EXCHANGE, CONDN_CODES, BUY_BRK, SELL_BRK, 
    (SELECT VALUE from TICKDATA AS td1 WHERE td1.ID = (SELECT max(ID) FROM TICKDATA AS td2 WHERE td2.TICKER = tickdata.TICKER AND td2.ID < tickdata.ID AND TYPE = "BEST_BID") ) AS LATEST_BBID,
    (SELECT VALUE from TICKDATA AS td1 WHERE td1.ID = (SELECT max(ID) FROM TICKDATA AS td2 WHERE td2.TICKER = tickdata.TICKER AND td2.ID < tickdata.ID AND TYPE = "BEST_ASK") ) AS LATEST_BASK
FROM tickdata
WHERE 
    TICKER = "AC CN" AND 
    TYPE = "TRADE" AND
    TIME > "2021-05-07T13:45:00.00" AND
    TIME <= "2021-05-07T14:00:00.00";
```

so what i tried next is using a window function, written as follows:

```
SELECT
    ID, TICKER, TIME, TYPE, VALUE, SIZE, EXCHANGE, CONDN_CODES, BUY_BRK, SELL_BRK,
    LAG(VALUE) 
        OVER
            (
                PARTITION BY TICKER
                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN TYPE = "BEST_BID" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), ID
            ) AS LATEST_BBID
FROM tickdata
WHERE 
    TICKER = "AC CN" AND 
    TYPE = "TRADE" AND
    TIME > "2021-05-07T13:45:00.00" AND
    TIME <= "2021-05-07T14:00:00.00";
```

but the window function is even slower!

so my question comes down to the following:

-Can I re-write the query or window function in such a way as to substantially increase performance?

-If there is no way to do this with a query or window function in a performant way, can/should I use something like a trigger to automatically update the latest best bid / latest best offer during the INSERT operation? After that I could just SELECT * and get all the data without SQLite performing any calculations on the fly.

-Lastly, if that wouldn't work either, should I use some other type of database?

thank you for your help!

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: @Shawn - i had indexed ID (primary key), and TIME. After your question, i added indexes on TYPE and TICKER, and that reduced query times by a huge factor. The query only takes 3 seconds to run now. Thank you for pointing this out, Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish you gave some sample data to test with. Would you try a query like this:

```
with best(ticker, type, id) as 
(
SELECT ticker, Type, max(ID) 
    FROM TICKDATA 
    WHERE  TYPE in ('BEST_BID', 'BEST_ASK')
    group by ticker, type
),
bids as 
(
   select td.ticker, td.value
   from tickdata td
   inner join best b on td.id = b.id
   where b.type = 'BEST_BID'
),
asks as
(
   select td.ticker, td.value
   from tickdata td
   inner join best b on td.id = b.id
   where b.type = 'BEST_ASK'
)
SELECT 
    t.ID, t.TICKER, t.TIME, t.TYPE, t.VALUE, t.SIZE, t.EXCHANGE, t.CONDN_CODES, t.BUY_BRK, t.SELL_BRK, 
    bids.value AS LATEST_BBID,
    asks.value AS LATEST_BASK
FROM tickdata  t 
inner join bids on t.ticker = bid.ticker
inner join asks on t.ticker = ask.tciker
WHERE 
    t.TICKER = "AC CN" AND 
    t.TYPE = "TRADE" AND
    t.TIME > "2021-05-07T13:45:00.00" AND
    t.TIME <= "2021-05-07T14:00:00.00";
```

Comment: thank you, Cetin. I tried this query and it also works. I tried adding more indexes, and that greatly sped up the query as well, which solves my problem. Thank you for your time!